# passing php variable in mysql update

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pass global variable in $_post in following way..
Unable to get through..Please help

```
 <?php
include '/home/mechdipl/db.inc';

echo $_GET['lec'];

$lect=$_GET['lec'];
$atnds=$_GET['atnds'];

$size = count($_POST['id']);

$i = 0;

while ($i < $size) {

    $name = $_POST['name'][$i];
    $lectr = $_POST[$lect][$i];
    $atndsr = $_POST[$atnds][$i];
    $id = $_POST['id'][$i];

    $query = "UPDATE stud SET name='$name', $lect ='$lectr',$atnds ='$atndsr' WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1";

    mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
    echo "$name<br /><br /><em>Presenty Updated!</em><br /><br />"; 
    ++$i;
}
?>
```

Comment: Watch out **SQL Injection**. The query is weird too. It's rare to use `LIMIT` on `UPDATE` query and `id` is usually and integer, which does not require single quote to surround the value. Last, you sure you meant `$lect='$lectr'` where `$lect` is a variable?

Comment: You probably meant to use `lect ='$lectr', atnds ='$atndsr'` unless you do have columns named after those *undefined* variables. Are you even querying? `mysqli_query()` - `mysql_query()` or PDO? Hard to say which API you're using.

Comment: *"I even tried `"'.$variable."'`"* <= your quotes are off, but I know what you meant `'".$variable."'` - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything and `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Yes i know $lect is a varible which is obtained from $_get  and $lectr is the value from the table submitted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors in your query, use this

```
UPDATE stud SET name='$name', lect ='$lectr', atnds ='$atndsr'  
WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1
```

and you just wrote the query, not performing it, for that you have to use mysqli_query() or mysql_query() function....please let me know if you have any more doubts.  and even in your $_POST global variable you have used

```
$lectr = $_POST[$lect][$i];   $atndsr = $_POST[$atnds][$i];
```

I know that it is not correct way. So, please before querying print out $_POST global variable and then use those keys in above. It could be like this

```
$lectr = $_POST['lect'][$i];
$atndsr = $_POST['atnds'][$i];
```